# Angular 4 cli generated site does not load when integrated into WepApi project (VS 2015)

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2015

I cannot get the Angular quickstart project to run after replacing the cloned source with one generated from the CLI (v1.2.3) in Visual Studio 2015. It seems like the appModule is not being bootstrapped using F5 debugging.  Using ng serve does work as expected.  I don't think the proper injection is happening in the index.html file when the debugger starts.  There is no System.import('app') line in the cli generated index.html file.  This seems to be expected with the use of webpack.

Is there a setting / configuration that needs to be done in order for this to load as expected?

Comment: *There is no System.import('app') line in the cli generated index.html file. This seems to be expected with the use of webpack.* What? No! That is expected when working with systemjs, not webpack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some links that may help you:

https://viveklakhanpal.wordpress.com/2016/05/02/angular2-5min-quickstart-project-setup-with-visual-studio-2015/

[Angular 2 cli integration in visual studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41471862/angular-2-cli-integration-in-visual-studio-2015)

But there are two other choices you may want to consider:

1) Use the Angular templates provided by Visual Studio instead of the Angular CLI. They will give you more of the "F5" type of experience that you may be looking for.

OR

2) Use VSCode for the Angular part and do Angular how the CLI is expecting and do the back end part with Visual Studio as normal. Lots of devs I know in the .NET world are moving to this "right tool for the right job" approach. It greatly saves time by leveraging the benefits of the Angular CLI without the headaches of trying to get it to work in Visual Studio.

Believe me, I was a Visual Studio junkie ... so it was very difficult to even consider giving up the tool I had spent years of my life with. But I'm really glad that I moved to VS Code for Angular!

Comment: Thanks @DeborahK.  VS Code for Angular is where I'm netting out as well.